# Bundles over quasi-affine homogeneous spaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, lie-groups, complex-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a complex Lie group and $H$ be a closed subgroup and let $J$ be a algebraic subgroup of $G$. If $G/J$ is an quasi-affine. Then why the 
holomorphic canonical map $\pi: G/H \rightarrow G/J$  splits as follows

\begin{array}{ccccccccc} G/H & \xrightarrow{\pi} & G/J &  \\
 \searrow  & &\nearrow \\
& G/\bar H
\end{array}Where $\bar H$ is the Zariski-closure of $H$?